# Is it possible to append a new string to a variable outside an if statement from the body of an if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to accomplish with the code below is to add the word " you" to the variable "holis" when the if statement is executed.

The result that I am getting is "hey you" only when the if statement is fulfilled and the subsequent console.log.

However, when SetTimeout is executed again, I go back to the original "holis" variable (without the " you")

Is there a way in JavaScript to permanently append a string to a string? I already tried concat.

```
var holis = "hey"

    if (this.txt2.substr(this.txt2.length - 3) === "...") {

        this.txtElement2.innerHTML = `<span class="intro-text">${this.txt2}</span>`;

        holis += " you"

        console.log(holis)

    } else {
        this.txtElement2.innerHTML = `<span class="intro-text">${this.txt2}</span>`;
    }

    console.log(holis)

    setTimeout(() => this.type2(), this.wait2);

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your `type2` method is supposed to do?

Comment: I should have included it, but the type2 method is the method where this code is in, and it is supposed to display a string on the screen as if it were a typewriter

Comment: So it's maybe because of scopes. `holis` is regenerated each time you call this function. Just put the variable outside of the scope and it should be persistent.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use global variables in javascript, but if that's what you want to do your variable is most likely inside a function.